# Custom domain for filepicker.io files

Tags: filepicker.io

It would be nice to use

```
https://files.mydomain.com/api/file/hfdjasfjdasfldh
```

instead of

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hfdjasfjdasfldh
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
-Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature that we've enable for our enterprise+ custom plans. It's not available for the self service plans.

Comment: How much do custom plans run?